# PHP: If String[Index] is in Array, PHP: String from String[1] to String[last]

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, textinput

Is there a PHP call for in_str?

…something similar to in_array..

Am using an `if-else` to take the each word (`string`) in the `array` of strings (from a `form`-`input`-`text`) to see if the start index `[0]` is equal to a single character `string` in another `array`..

Also, how does one get at a `string` from `string[1]` to `string[last]`?

(these two questions are highlighted in the code using the format: `**code**`)

```
      if(isset($_POST['RadioButtonName']) &&
      $_POST['RadioButtonName'] == 'aValue') {
        $stringsArray = array($_POST['FormInputText']);
        $vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");

        foreach ($stringsArray as $stringsArrayString)
          {
            if (**in_str**($stringsArrayString[0], $vowels)) {
              echo $stringsArrayString . "aWord" . "<&nbsp;>";
            }
            else {
              echo "**$stringsArrayString[1] to $stringsArrayString[last]**" . "$stringsArrayString[0]" . "aWord" . "<&nbsp;>";
            }
          }
      }
```

Comment: Do you mean [strstr()](http://PHP.net/strstr)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use strpos to check if a letter is in a string, but to search an array you'll need to use a foreach...

```
    foreach($vowels as $vowel)
    {
        $firstLetterIsAVowel = (strpos($stringsArrayString, $vowel) === 0 ? true : false);
    }

        if ($firstLetterIsAVowel)) {
          echo $stringsArrayString . "aWord" . "<&nbsp;>";
        }
        else {
          echo "**".substr($stringsArrayString, 1) . "$stringsArrayString[0]" . "aWord" . "<&nbsp;>";
        }
```

note the use of === instead of == as strpos returns false if not found, and 0 == false.
I did it like that because that was your question, but i'd rather check if $stringArrayString[0] is a vowel like this...

```
    in_array ( $stringArrayString[0] , $vowels)
```